# roscpp memory usage

Tags: ros, memory, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used Valgrind to check memory usage in a program I'm creating and found out that the problem is mostly in rosccp.

```
==21986== 
==21986== 5,380,160 bytes in 3,440 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 161 of 161
==21986==    at 0x4C2CC70: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21986==    by 0x68A9637: getifaddrs_internal (ifaddrs.c:402)
==21986==    by 0x68AA19F: getifaddrs (ifaddrs.c:825)
==21986==    by 0x5328D15: ros::Transport::Transport() (in /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so)
==21986==    by 0x53342BF: ros::TransportTCP::TransportTCP(ros::PollSet*, int) (in /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so)
==21986==    by 0x5334716: ros::TransportTCP::accept() (in /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so)
==21986==    by 0x5335B52: ros::TransportTCP::socketUpdate(int) (in /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so)
==21986==    by 0x5364E4D: ros::PollSet::update(int) (in /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so)
==21986==    by 0x53022A7: ros::PollManager::threadFunc() (in /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so)
==21986==    by 0x739AA49: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.54.0)
==21986==    by 0x75AD181: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==21986==    by 0x688FFBC: clone (clone.S:111)
==21986== 
==21986== LEAK SUMMARY:
==21986==    definitely lost: 5,422,612 bytes in 3,469 blocks
==21986==    indirectly lost: 207,979 bytes in 4,227 blocks
==21986==      possibly lost: 2,467 bytes in 18 blocks
==21986==    still reachable: 3,376 bytes in 39 blocks
==21986==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21986== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==21986== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==21986== 
==21986== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==21986== ERROR SUMMARY: 30 errors from 30 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Is there anyway around it?
This test was made with the program running for only 5 minutes, after two hours with my program running it slows down considerably because of this memory usage.

==== EDIT ====

I'm adding here an example code that shows this behavior in my laptop:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"

#include "custom_pkg_msgs/CustomAction.h"
#include "custom_pkg_msgs/CustomSrv.h"

#include <mcheck.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // start ros
    ros::init(argc, argv, "test_node");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Rate loop_rate(1);

    srand (time(NULL)); // start random fucntions

    ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<custom_pkg_msgs::CustomAction>("/random_topic", 1000);

    // client to start game service and server for end game service
    ros::ServiceClient start_game_client = n.serviceClient<custom_pkg_msgs::CustomSrv>("/random_service");
    ros::service::waitForService("/random_service", -1);

    // spin to answer services
    ros::spin();

    // shutdown ros node
    ros::shutdown();
}
```

And in the terminal I run: `valgrind --leak-check=full --trace-children=yes rosrun custom_package test_node`

I'm running valgrind-3.10.0.SVN on a Ubuntu 14.04, 64bits and with ROS indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196605/roscpp-memory-usage/) by [t.pimentel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4923/t.pimentel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2014-11-03

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-03**:
It would probably help if you could post the code that you are running through Valgrind.

**Comment by [t.pimentel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4923/t.pimentel/) on 2014-11-03**:
I edited my question with an example code.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-11-04**:
As in [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/129856/roscpp-and-valgrind-memory-leaks/) question, Valgrind versions can differ greatly in their sophistication when it comes to detecting leaks. Could you add some version information to your OP? ROS, OS, valgrind?

**Comment by [t.pimentel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4923/t.pimentel/) on 2014-11-04**:
I'm using valgrind-3.10.0.SVN on a Ubuntu 14.04, 64bits and ROS indigo.

A task manager, htop, also exposes this problem. The memory used by the ROS program increases indefinitely.

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2014-11-04**:
Could you describe what other nodes you have running? I'm not able to reproduce the memory leak by just running the code posted here - do you have subscribers on the chatter_pub topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like it's ticketed here: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/570

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0